# continues css selector names

Tags: css

I need to have css selector names continuously.
For eg.

```
eng1, eng2, eng3 ...... eng100 {
   display: block;
   width:100px;
   height:20px;
}
```

Is there any way to mention css like array kind?
Thanks for your help.

Comment: first of all ... why ? why not apply the same class to multiple elements, as is the intended use ?

Comment: Yes surely you could just name that class .eng then extend that class for specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use one of the [CSS3 substring matching selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#attribute-substrings)

```
[class^="eng"]{
   display: block;
   width:100px;
   height:20px;
}
```

which will match all elements that have a class attribute that starts with "eng"

---

**Important**

If you have other classes on the same element that come before the `eng??` class it will fail.

For example

```
<div class="someother eng5">..</div>
```

will **not** be matched, as the selector checks the whole class attribute as a string.

Comment: I am not sure this would help my situation. I am trying to use DOM to de-reference select boxes/tags based on id value. Hence the requirement!

Answer (score 3):

If this is a case of generated classes, you could use an attribute selector:

```
*[class^="eng"] {
    // styles
}
```

You *could* create a long list of selectors like that using Sass, but I wouldn't recommend it unless you *really* need to support old browsers that don't understand the attribute selector.